Kalman filtering using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro 3
I am trying to run a Kalman filter in ArcGIS Pro 3.1. I have pulled together and tried running the following code. It runs without error, but the featureclass that it creates is empty.
Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?
import os
import numpy as np
import arcpy

def kalman_filter_2d(points, initial_state, initial_uncertainty, process_noise, measurement_noise):
    smoothed_points = []
    state_estimate = initial_state
    uncertainty_estimate = initial_uncertainty

    for point in points:
        x, y, z = point
        measurement = np.array([[x], [y], [z]])

        # Prediction step
        state_estimate = state_estimate  # No control input
        uncertainty_estimate = uncertainty_estimate + process_noise

        # Measurement update step
        kalman_gain = uncertainty_estimate @ np.linalg.inv(uncertainty_estimate + measurement_noise)
        state_estimate = state_estimate + kalman_gain @ (measurement - state_estimate)
        uncertainty_estimate = (np.eye(3) - kalman_gain) @ uncertainty_estimate

        smoothed_points.append(state_estimate.flatten())

    return np.array(smoothed_points)

# Parameters
initial_state = np.array([[0], [0], [0]])
initial_uncertainty = np.eye(3)
process_noise = np.eye(3) * 0.1
measurement_noise = np.eye(3) * 0.5

# Update these paths with your actual data paths
input_fc = r'C:\Arc GIS\Test Glasgow 2.0\Adjustfielddatafordem.shp'  # Path to your input shapefile
output_fc = r'C:\Users\purni\Documents\Test\FilterPointsnew3.shp'  # Path to your output shapefile
fields = ['SHAPE@XY', 'Elevation']  # Ensure this matches the field names in your data

# Initialize a list to hold the points
points = []

# Read data from the input feature class
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x, y = row[0]
        z = row[1]
        points.append([x, y, z])  # Append the point to the list

# Convert the list of points to a NumPy array
points = np.array(points)

# Apply the Kalman filter
smoothed_points = kalman_filter_2d(points, initial_state, initial_uncertainty, process_noise, measurement_noise)

# Create the output feature class and add the smoothed points
output_path = r'C:\Users\purni\Documents\Test'  # Path to the directory where you want to save the output
output_name = 'FilterPointsnew3.shp'  # Name of the output shapefile
output_fc_path = os.path.join(output_path, output_name)  # Corrected path concatenation

# Create the output feature class
arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(output_path, output_name, 'POINT')

# Verify if the feature class is created before adding fields
if arcpy.Exists(output_fc_path):
    arcpy.AddField_management(output_fc_path, "Elevation", "DOUBLE")

    # Insert smoothed points into the output feature class
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_fc_path, ['SHAPE@XY', 'Elevation']) as cursor:
        for smoothed_point in smoothed_points:
            x, y, z = smoothed_point
            cursor.insertRow([(x, y), z])
            
    print("2D Kalman filtering completed and results saved.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to create the output feature class at {output_fc_path}")


I would put in a print statement to print the  smoothed_points and verify that the array contains data.
